# Modulus square of an complex expression

Tags: complex, algebraic-manipulation

I have an expression:

```
E^(I*((-k)*x + \[Xi] - (t + 1/2)^y/(\[Beta]*Subscript[b, 2]*(Subscript[a, 2] + 2*k*Subscript[b, 2]))))
```

I want to get modulus square of this expression. As I know, if the all parameters are reals,the modulus square should be 1. But I can' t get this via Mathematica using following code:

```
    ComplexExpand[
  Abs[E^(I*((-k)*x + \[Xi] - (t + 1/2)^y/(\[Beta]*Subscript[b, 2]*(Subscript[a, 2] + 2*k*Subscript[b, 2]))))]^2]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You should avoid using subscripts in general for this kind of manipulation. With that said, you could use the `TargetFunctions` option of `ComplexExpand[]`, and then use `FullSimplify[]` with suitable assumptions.

Comment: If the magnitude of your expression would be 1, this implies  that the exponent is purely imaginary. This further implies  that the expression after "I" is purely real. However, this expression contains  "(t + 1/2)^y" what can take an complex value.

Comment: @DanielHuber is right - when you get rid of `y` or replace it by any real number larger than 1/2 then the modulus square becomes one.